# R raster plot even legend

Tags: r, plot, raster, netcdf4

I tried to use NetCDF file to draw a raster map in R using `raster` and `ncdf4` packages.

The range of my data is too large, but almost my data distributes within 0-2000. You can look at the histogram of my data:

[image]

[image]

So I want to draw a plot with the interval of 200, like `seq(0, 2000, 200)`.
But when I used these intervals, the values which are larger than 2000 were recognized by R as `NA` when drawing the plot. These large values are printed as transparent when drawing.

[image]

The plot using even intervals:

[image]

I tried to give large intervals to the plot, like `breaks = c(seq(0, 1500, 100), 40000)`, but the legend of the plot looks ugly.

In a word, I want a plot with even interval and legend. Something like an open range, not a closed range.

The following plot is my desirable plot realized by other software. How can I resolve my problems using R?

[image]

My code is here:

```
    library(rgdal)
    library(raster)
    library(ncdf4)
    library(rasterVis)
    library(sp)

    ncname <- "output.nc"
    ncdata <- nc_open(ncname)
    bb <- raster(ncname)

    hist(bb)
    hist(bb, xlim = c(0, 2000), breaks = seq(0, 40000, 500))

    plot(bb)
    plot(bb, xlim = c(25, 53), asp = 1.5,  breaks = c(seq(0, 1500, 100), 40000), col = topo.colors(20)) 

    plot(bb, legend.only = FALSE, zlim = c(0, 2000), col = topo.colors(20), asp = 1.5,
         legend.width = 1, legend.shrink = 1.0,
         axis.args = list(at = seq(0, 2000, 100),
         labels = seq(0, 2000, 100)))
```

Comment: I wonder if `breaks = c(seq(0, 2000, 100), Inf)` would work?

Comment: Your answer didn't work. It must be a finite number.
Thank you all the same.

Comment: I can turn the values which are larger than 2000 to 2000.

Like this: values(bb)[values(bb)>=2000] = 2000.

Comment: That would be my next suggestion... :) You could have a legend entry of `>= 2000`.

Comment: Yes, this is the only way I can find now.
When I have other solution, I will update it.
Thanks.